# SQL Server Management Studio ignoring carriage returns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have an `INSERT` like this:

```
INSERT INTO Queries (query) 
values ('select * from person 
         where id = 1 
         and idtype=2')
```

I then perform a `SELECT` like this:

```
SELECT Query 
FROM Queries
```

However, the result in SQL Server Management Studio is like this:

```
select * from person where id = 1 and idtype=2
```

I want a result like this:

```
select * from person 
    where id = 1 
    and idtype=2
```

How do I achieve this? SQL Server Management Studio seems to ignore carriage returns.

I recall reading a question on here some time ago which suggested using XML Path. The queries column is a `varchar(100)`.

Comment: What type is your 'query' column? Are you using the column output or using the 'output as text'?

Comment: @rodrigogq , it is a varchar(100).  I have edited the question.

Comment: @rodrigogq, I don't know what 'output by text' is, so no.

Comment: If your output is set to grid you won't see row breaks, try setting output to text instead. (Using ctrl+t)

Comment: @jpw, thanks.  That is what I wanted.  How do I set it back to grid?

Comment: @w0051977 ctrl+d sets output to grid. There are buttons to change it in one of the toolbars. If you hover over the button you'll see the shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use to insert texts in my columns with several carriage returns.

Do display this, try changing your query output as text instead of column. There should be a button in toolbox for that, but you can change it on Sql output options and preferences too.

Comment: When I output as text, part of the end of the query is chopped of.  Why is this?

Comment: There's a text (column) size limit for display. You can change that on options/preferences.

Comment: I cannot find Preferences in the Options window.

Comment: I think I have found it.  It is in Query Options (not Options) and Results/Text (not preferences).

Answer (score 0):

the carriage returns are there but they don't show in the grid results. try to copy and paste the results to a new query window or a text editor to check.